# ReactJs, how can I prevent page from re-render when navigate back using react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

So I have 2 pages 1. customer-list, 2. customer-detail. so customer-list page will be a table where it contains a list of a customer-id without the details but there's a button which will navigate to another page customer detail. the code looks like this

```
const CustomerList = () => {
   const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
   useEffect(() => { fetch customer list here }, [])

   return (
      { 
         customers.map(c => 
            <tr>
              <td>{customer.customer_id}</td>
              <td><button onClick={() => navigate(`/customer/${customer.customer_id}`)}>View details</button></td>
           </tr>
         ) 
      }
   );
}
```

In the customer details page there's also a button where it can navigate back to the previous page, customer-list, the code looks like this.

```
const CustomerDetails = () => {
   const navigate = useNavigate();

   return (
       <>
        <h2>Customer Details</h2>
        <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Back</button>
       </>
   );
}
```

however when I navigate back to the first page it will completely re-render and fetch the whole data again. Is there a way to cache or prevent the first page from re-rendering or re-load the data because it took very long time to load the customer list so I'm concerning about the user experience here. I'm using react-router-dom v6 and the  path structure looks like this.

```
/ -> root customer-list
/customer/:customerId -> customer-details
```

Answer (score 0):

With the way you have implemented your `CustomerList` component, it will always try to fetch the API whenever it mounts, because the state is local to that component only. To prevent this from happening, you have few options

1. Move the `customers` state to its Parent and pass it via props to `CustomerList` component. Please keep in mind that if that Parent is also something that gets unmonted & remounted on route changes, then this will still happen. So you will have to lift the state again till a Parent that is always rendered. You can decide this based on whether or not its good to keep this data in such a parent
2. Use a global state solution. This way, data will be kept separate from your components so that it is not lost when you navigate back and forth. Redux is one of them. There are many also.
3. Use some data fetching libraries like SWR or TanstackQuery. They have builtin mechanisms to keep the cache

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet , to achieve this behavior. There is an amazing example on the link I provided

From the link

```js
function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>

      {/* This element will render either <DashboardMessages> when the URL is
          "/messages", <DashboardTasks> at "/tasks", or null if it is "/"
      */}
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
        <Route
          path="messages"
          element={<DashboardMessages />}
        />
        <Route path="tasks" element={<DashboardTasks />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Or if don't wanna change your current routing setup and not use a global state manager you can use `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` or any browser storage API that would fit your use case, this will persist your data and you don't need to re-fetch it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Answer (score 0):

The `CustomerList` component is going to "rerender" regardless when the route rendering it is navigated to and `CustomerList` is mounted. Because of this any `useEffect` hook calls will be invoked again. It seems rather your question is "how to prevent refetching the same data again when navigating back to a page". For this the solution is simple; it's the classic "Lifting state up" pattern. See [Lifting State Up](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) from the legacy docs or [Sharing State Between Components](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components) from the current docs.

You just need to move the `customers` state and fetching logic ***up*** the ReactTree to a more stable location that remains mounted while the app is navigating between these two routes. The next logical location is to move it to a parent layout route component and to pass the data down to children routes via its `Outlet` component.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const CustomerLayout = () => {
  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch customer list here
  }, []);

  return <Outlet context={{ customers }} />
};
```

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route path="/customer" element={<CustomerLayout />}>
    <Route index element={<CustomerList />} />
    <Route path=":customerId" element={<CustomerDetails />} />
  </Route>
  ...
</Routes>
```

The nested route's elements will use the [`useOutletContext`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context) hook to access the passed-down `customer` state.

```
import { useNavigate, useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

const CustomerList = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { customers } = useOutletContext();

  return customers.map(customer => (
    <tr key={customer.customer_id}>
      <td>{customer.customer_id}</td>
      <td>
        <button onClick={() => navigate(customer.customer_id)}>
          View details
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ));
};
```

```
import { useNavigate, useOutletContext, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const CustomerDetails = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { customers } = useOutletContext();
  const { customerId } = useParams();

  const details = customers.find(customer => customer.customer_id === customerId);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Customer Details</h2>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Back</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

If for some reason placing the state and fetching logic in `CustomerLayout` still fetches it too often, then continue pushing it *up* the ReactTree to a stable common ancestor component.